# How to get values to the outside from three functions and update them in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which lets users to add number of participants for an event. in it I used input type number field to get number of participants. then I calculate how much fee they have to pay for each passenger type. I have 3 passenger types.

My table looks like this,

[image]

I use `keyup mouseup` bind to get the input value by user and multiplied it with fee for one participant.

```
var totalAdults;

jQuery("#number_adults").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
var numOfAdults = jQuery("#number_adults").val();

totalAdults = numOfAdults * adultFee;

});
```

I have 3 of above functions to calculate and real time display how much fee that they have to pay in each passenger type.

Now I need to get the total sum of all three passenger type fees and display/update it in real time to the user, at the end of my table.

I tried making each passenger type total value `global` and calculating it's sum, but I get an error saying missing semicolon error linked to this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)

I'm stuck here. **how can I get total value on all three passenger types outside their respective functions and display that value correctly in real time**? (when they update number of passengers, total for passenger type is changing, I need to change final total accordingly). please help

### Update:

this is the html table that I used. this get repeated another two times for other two passenger types.

```js
var adultFee = 150;
var finalTotal = 0;

jQuery("#number_adults").bind('keyup mouseup', function() {
  var numOfAdults = jQuery("#number_adults").val();
  totalAdults = numOfAdults * adultFee;
  jQuery("#adult_amount").html(totalAdults);

  // console.log(totalAdults);
  finalTotal = finalTotal + totalAdults;
  console.log(finalTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600;">Adult</td>
  <td id="adult_price" name="adult_price">150.00</td>
  <td>
    <input id="number_adults" max="3" min="1" name="number_adults" type="number" value="0" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td name="amount">
    <p id="adult_amount"></p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is how I tried to get the final total, it doesn't display any result

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#adult_amount', function() {
finalTotal = finalTotal+totalAdults;

alert(finalTotal);
});
```

Comment: Show us the complete code please.

Comment: You should try using `onchange` event by the way.

Comment: @void updated. please see now

Comment: Side note: .bind() has been deprecated for 3 years, and was actually first superseded 8 years ago! As per the jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/bind/), you should be using [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: Anyway, I made your code into a runnable demo (see edited question). it doesn't produce any syntax errors. If you have a syntax error about semicolons, it's coming from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @ADyson how can I update my code with .on() ? as shown in the image, I have input type number, input field. also syntax error comes when I try use this outside the above three functions ` console.log(adultTotal);`

Comment: "how can I update my code with .on()" ...by reading the docs to see the syntax and the accepted parameters, but in the basic case you can usually just do a find/replace to change `.bind(` to `.on(`

Comment: just replace .bind with .on? @ADyson

Comment: yes, exactly. They do have slightly different signatures (as you'll see if you read the docs), but in the case you've shown above, you won't break anything

Comment: @ADyson sorry, I found it. thanks. but my main question still remains. can you please help me? even a little something'd be great

Comment: If you have a syntax error you want us to fix, then you'll have to show us a version of the code which actually produces the syntax error. We can't guess exactly what you've done wrong. You mention you wrote `console.log(adultTotal);` which produces the error, but that line, within itself, is valid. It's probably something to do with where you've put it, but you haven't shown that. Make us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, otherwise we cannot do anything except speculate about your problem. We are not mind-readers. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I updated my question a bit. All I want is get total values from the each functions (outside the functions), then calculate the final total and display t to the user. final total should be automatically updated when any of the passenger totals get changed. can you help me with that please? not with the syntax error problem

Comment: Ok. If you're struggling some other way with getting the total for the three passenger types, then it's not clear specifically how you're struggling (if not the syntax error)...because you haven't shown any code or HTML for the other two types, or explained what precisely goes wrong when you try to do the calculation or read from those fields. Again our information is incomplete. Show us all the table rows, and all the code, and explain what happens when you try to run it. Again [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: @ADyson added the method I tried to get the final total. please see now. should it be easier if I used select other than input[number] in this case?

Comment: the "adult_amount" element is a `<p>` (paragraph) element, not an input field, so it doesn't have a `value` property (so you can't use jQuery's .val() methd to access it (and your code forgot the function brackets `()` as well...)). You should use the .text() method instead to get the content of such an element. It also won't trigger a "change" event when it's updated. In general, the only HTML elements which have a "value" property, and trigger a "change" event are form fields.

Comment: @ADyson I even tried using `finalTotal = finalTotal+totalAdults;` but it still didnt work. Im stuck in *get total value on all three passenger types outside their respective functions*

Comment: To be honest it's not clear to me why you would actually need to do that part? When each field is updated, its function runs and updates the final total into the variable, and into a place on the screen. If you ever need to get the final total in another piece of code, then you can just read from that variable (assuming it's a global). I don't know _when_ you want to do that, but I can't really see how it's causing you a problem - partly because, despite my requests, you **still** haven't provided an example which actually demonstrates this issue in a reproducible way....

Comment: ...Random lines of code posted in the comments without any context around them doesn't demonstrate the issue, especially when the only description I get is "doesn't work" ....doesn't work **how** exactly? I think you _probably_ have a scope issue with `totalAdults` only existing within the change callback? Nonetheless give me a few minutes and I'll try and make a demo which does what I _think_ you want to do using what I think is _probably_ your field names and table structure. If you want something more precise, then you need to give me more precise information to begin with.

Comment: Ok I have written an answer with what I hope is a comprehensive explanation of what needed to be done. You can run the demo to see how it works. Please post comments under it if there's anything specific you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop on every rows on the table and calculate the total sum and also the individual. Here i done by the dynamic method. if the total of each passenger is inserted in a unique input, then you can access from that input. Otherwise please follow the method

```js
$(document).on('keyup mouseup','.qty', function() {
     calculate();
});

function calculate(){
  var finalTotal = 0;
  var old = 0;
  var mature = 0;
  var adult = 0;
  $('.qty').each(function(key,value){
    $qty = $(this).val();
    $type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $amount = $(this).parent().siblings('.adult_price').html();
    $total = Number($qty) * parseFloat($amount);
    $(this).parent().siblings('.amount').html($total);
    finalTotal += $total;
   
   if($type == 'adult')
      adult += parseFloat($total);
   else if($type == 'mature')
      mature += parseFloat($total);
   else if($type == 'old')
      old += parseFloat($total);

  });
  
  $('.grandTotal').html(finalTotal);
   
   // console.log('Adult',adult);
   // console.log('Mature',mature);
   // console.log('Old',old);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Passenger Types</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Adult</b></td>
     <td class="adult_price" name="adult_price">150.00</td>
     <td>
        <input max="3" min="1" name="number_adults" type="number" value="0" class="form-control qty" data-type="adult">
      </td>
      <td name="amount" class='amount'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Mature</b></td>
     <td class="adult_price" name="adult_price">200.50</td>
     <td>
        <input max="3" min="1" name="number_adults" type="number" value="0" class="form-control qty" data-type="mature">
      </td>
      <td name="amount" class='amount'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Old</b></td>
     <td class="adult_price" name="adult_price">150.00</td>
     <td>
        <input max="3" min="1" name="number_adults" type="number" value="0" class="form-control qty" data-type="old">
      </td>
      <td name="amount" class='amount'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><b>Grand Total</b></td>
      <td class='grandTotal'>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: solutions are nice but they should always be accompanied by explanation of what you have changed and why it helps. Don't assume the OP (or anyone else reading) a) understands what you did, or b) has the inclination to study your code to try and figure it out. Help them to like your answer by giving details! Also it's bad practice to effectively encourage people to just copy/paste code without really knowing what it does or which are the significant parts.

Comment: @ADyson: Thanks for the messgae. it's mistakenly posted. I edited the code again and updated now

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see any commentary on your code yet

Answer (score 1):

I made a working example for you.

```js
$('.inputs').each(function(){
  $(this).on('change keyup', function(){
    let sumTotal = 0;
    $('.inputs').each(function(){
      sumTotal += $(this).val() * +$(this).parent().next().data('price');
    });
    $('.total').text(`${sumTotal} $`);
  });
});
```

```css
td:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(3){
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>QTY</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Child</td>
              <td><input type="number" class="inputs form-control" value="0" min="0" max="999"></td>
              <td class="price" data-price="150">150 $</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Adult</td>
              <td><input type="number" class="inputs form-control" value="0" min="0" max="999"></td>
              <td class="price" data-price="200">200 $</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Adult Plus</td>
              <td><input type="number" class="inputs form-control" value="0" min="0" max="999"></td>
              <td class="price" data-price="250">250 $</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Total - </td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="total">0.00 $</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(https://codepen.io/bichiko/pen/JQWomy)

Comment: again see my comments on the other answers about explaining what you've done, not just posting a slew of code for people to blindly copy (or just not fully understand)

Comment: @wydyq You are welcome. If you think that was helpful please give me upvote

Comment: I tried, seems like I cant. something with not enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which should do what you need.

Compared to your code, the key changes are:

- Use classes instead of IDs to identify the elements within each row. This means you can handle changes to all your fields using the same event handling code. I've given all your quantity fields the `.qty` class, and then bound the event to that class, so all elements with that class will run the same function.
- Within the function, I've stripped out all direct references to fields - instead, to get the price field, and the total field for the relevant type, the code uses the positions of the fields relative to each other in the page, it uses the .parent(), .next(), and .prev() functions to find the total and amount fields which are within the same table row as the altered quantity field (which will always be `this` inside the event handler), so that it does the calculations on the right fields.
- To calculate the final overall total, I've defined a separate function. Again this uses a class selector to identify all the "amount" fields, and add each of those values together to get the total. Since this function is triggered at the end of the event handler, it will always update the grand total whenever one of the quantities is updated.

Other minor changes:

- use .on() instead of the [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) .bind()

```js
jQuery(".qty").on('keyup mouseup', function() {
  var tdElement = jQuery(this).parent();
  var qty = parseInt(this.value);
  var fee = parseFloat(tdElement.prev(".price").text());
  var typeTotal = qty * fee;
  tdElement.next(".amount").html(typeTotal);
  calcFinalTotal();
});

function calcFinalTotal()
{
  var finalTotal = 0;
  $(".amount").each(function() {
   finalTotal += parseFloat($(this).text());
  });
  $("#total").text(finalTotal); 
}
```

```css
td, th
{
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align:left;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Passenger Type</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Total</th>
<tr>
  <th>Adult</th>
  <td class="price">150.00</td>
  <td>
    <input max="3" min="1" name="number_adults" type="number" value="0" class="form-control qty">
  </td>
  <td class="amount">0
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Type 2</th>
  <td class="price" id="type3_price">200.00</td>
  <td>
    <input max="3" min="1" name="number_type" type="number" value="0" class="form-control qty">
  </td>
  <td class="amount">0
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Type 3</th>
  <td class="price" id="type3_price">200.00</td>
  <td>
    <input max="3" min="1" name="number_type" type="number" value="0" class="form-control qty">
  </td>
  <td class="amount">0
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">Grand Total</th>
<td id="total"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is very flexible use class instead of id. If you use inputs, selects, etc you should delegate the `input` or `change` event to them.

```
$('input').on('input', function() {...
```

`input` event will trigger as soon as user types or selects on or to an input tag. `change` event will trigger when a user types or selects on or to an input *and* then clicks (`unfocus` or `blur` event) elsewhere.

The HTML is slightly modified for consistency. Note that there are 2 extra inputs per `<tr>`.

When using input inside tables you can traverse the DOM by first referencing the imputed/changed/clicked tag as `$(this)` then *climb* up to the parent `<td>` and from there either go to the next `<td>` using `.next()` or go to the previous `<td>` using `.prev()`. Once you get to a neighboring `<td>` use `.find()` to get the input within. When extracting a number from an input it is normally a string but with jQuery method `.val()` it should extract input value as a number automatically.  Details commented in demo.

```js
/*
//A - Any tag with the class of .qty that the user inputs data into triggers a function
//B - Get the value of the imputed .qty (ie $(this)) 
//C - reference $(this) parent <td> go to the next <td> then find a tag with the class .price and get its value
//D - reference $(this) parent <td> go to the previous <td> then find a tag with the class of .total then set its value to the product of qty and price and fix it with hundredths (.00 suffix)
//E - Declare an empty array
//F - Get the value of each .total, convert it into a number then push the number into the empty array
//G - Use .reduce() to get the sum of all values within the array then fix it with hundredths (.00 suffix) and set it as the value of .grand
*/
$('.qty').on('input', function() { //A
  var qty = $(this).val(); //B
  var price = $(this).parent().prev('td').find('.price').val(); //C
  $(this).parent().next('td').find('.total').val((qty * price).toFixed(2)); //D

  var totals = []; //E
  $('.total').each(function() {
    totals.push(Number($(this).val()));
  }); //F
  $('.grand').val(totals.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur).toFixed(2)); //G
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 6ch
}

[readonly] {
  border: 0;
  width: 6ch;
  text-align: right
}

[type=number] {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Adult</td>
    <td><input class="price" name='price' value='150.00' readonly></td>
    <td>
      <input class="qty" name="qty" min="0" max="3" type="number" value="0" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="total" name='total' readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Senior</td>
    <td><input class="price" name='price' value='100.00' readonly></td>
    <td>
      <input class="qty" name="qty" min="0" max="3" type="number" value="0" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="total" name='total' readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: 600;">Child</td>
    <td><input class="price" name='price' value='75.00' readonly></td>
    <td>
      <input class="qty" name="qty" min="0" max="3" type="number" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="total" name='total' readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3' style='text-align:right;'>Total</td>
    <td><input class='grand' name='grand' value='0' readonly></td>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think there's supposed to be an overall total field at the bottom as well

Answer (score -1):

This is axample of yours problem, try using object

```js
var data = {a:0, b:0, c: 0} 

function one (){
  data.a = data.a + 10
  console.log(data.a)
  total()
}

function two (){
  data.b = data.b + 10
  total()
  console.log(data.b)
}

function three () {
  data.c = data.c + 30
  total()
  console.log(data.c)
}

function total () {
  var totaly = data.a + data.b + data.c
  console.log('Total input :', totaly)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="one()"> get A </button>
<button onclick="two()"> get B</button>
<button onclick="three()"> get  C </button>
```

Comment: TBH I can't really see how this is particularly related to this problem. If you're going to give an example using completely different code you should explain how each part relates to OP's code. Better to use their code if possible though. Also, OP wants total to be auto-calculated, but this doesn't do that. So all in all it's not particularly helpful IMO

Comment: Silent, i inspired him not just give him directly answer, its forum to share. do something to help people

Comment: Ok but the point of posting an answer here is to actually answer the question and definitively solve the problem, not to give hints / tutorials / suggestions, and especially not without an _explanation_ of the limitations of the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Your answer doesn't really "help" because it's devoid of any contextual information.

Comment: ? which one say definitively solve the problem, not to give hints / tutorials / suggestions, everybody give hints, they tutor the people, Write to the best of your ability We don't expect every answer to be perfect, if i read correctly, please tell me if im wrong, im new of this

Comment: @wydyq You are welcome. If you think that was helpful please give me upvote

Comment: I tried, seems like I cant. something with not enough reputation

Comment: @KEKUATAN no one said perfect...but upvotes and downvotes are still a measure of quality. The help article says "What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that". Your answer doesn't, it gives an example using a totally different set of code and doesn't provide the most important piece of requested functionality. Even if you are going to give an answer which is just " in the right direction", the article tells you need to explain that, which you haven't done.I wrote my own answer, you can compare it with yours and see if you can see a difference.